# When do I use if/endif versus If{}?

Tags: php, if-statement

Well the question is self explanatory.

In PHP when do I use the `if/endif` notation instead of the standard `if(something){}` notation?

Example:

```
<?php if($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

Versus:

```
<?php if($a == 5){ ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: im gonna guess for templating, but i feel like im wrong

Comment: I thought it was for VB programmers... ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Others have given the answer "for templating", but haven't really explained why.  Curly braces are great for denoting blocks, but they kind of rely on indentation to be read clearly.  So this is fairly clear:

```
<?php
if (1 == 2)
{
    while (1 < 2)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

It's obvious which brace matches which.

If, however, you're going into an HTML block, you're probably going to stop indenting cleanly.  For instance:

```
<?php
if (1 != 2) { ?>
<div>This always happens! <?php while (true) { ?>
  <p>This is going to cause an infinite loop!</p>
<?php }
}
```

That's hard to follow.  If you use the `endif` style, it looks a little cleaner:

```
<?php
if (1 != 2): ?>
<div>This always happens! <?php while (true): ?>
  <p>This is going to cause an infinite loop!</p>
<?php endwhile;
endif;
```

The content of the code shows more clearly what's being done.  For this limited case, it's more legible.

Comment: @lonesomeday, how do you do nested `if`'s in that last example?

Comment: `if(something){do something if(something2){//do something2}else {}}` how do i do that with the shorter notation?

Comment: `if(something): doSomething(); if (something2): doSomething2(); else: endif; endif;`  It's not exactly great, I agree.  I, [like Edorian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023418/when-do-i-use-if-endif-versus-if/6023441#6023441) basically never use this syntax.

Comment: I don't use it either, i am basically asking if I would, should i, also you left out the `else` in your example

Comment: How does php know which `if` the `else` is referring to? with reg sytax there are brackets, but here there is nothing.

Comment: @Neal The same way it knows which `endif` it is: whichever is the most recently opened `if` block that hasn't been closed yet.

Comment: hmmmmm ok. i guess that makes sense

Comment: This is basically how I use it. I used if/endif in views where there's lots of html between, but in the controller, I use if(){}. I think it's easier to read with if/endif in views. Also, and this is a lazy ass reason, my code editor closes curly brackets automatically, which is nice when I try to write a code block, but kind of annoying when I want to close the php tag and then write html.

Answer (score 17):

Short answer:

**Always use** `if($something) { }` and pretty much **never use** `if/endif`. It's standard since PHP 4.0.0 and while the old syntax is not going away this is the one everybody expects.

If you are really looking for a case where you can use if/endif then it's when using php as a template language.

Some people like something like this:

```
<?php if ($foo): ?>
Hi There
<?php else: ?>
cya!
<?php endif; ?>
```

better than

```
<?php if ($foo) { ?>
Hi There
<?php } else { ?>
cya!
<?php } ?>
```

and imho it is because every line "speaks" and that can be helpful when there is a lot of html inbetween the php tags.

Comment: I don't think this is true; it's not that `if {}` is a standard, per se, it's just that it's preferred for readability in some places. For example, in a template: `<?php if ($var) { ?>yay!<?php } ?>` is just plain ugly, compared to `<?php if ($var): ?>yay!<?php endif; ?>`. Note that the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) doesn't note any deprecations or notices even.

Comment: @Jimmy i tried to say that the old syntax is not going away with "and while the old syntax is not going away". Was that not clear? Sorry! And i personally agree with you on the syntax choice in templates, but I've heard from other people that they don't like it so i didn't want to talk in absolutes here

Comment: Agree 100%.  I'll also add though that if you indent your code properly, you should never have a problem telling where the block starts and ends.  Which therefore negates one of the primary reasons for using `endif`...

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are acceptable. Some people maintain that the alternative syntax (endif) is more legible in templates. IMHO, with a modern syntax coloring/highlighting error, that no longer holds true. Just pick a style and stick with it.

Comment: Old question, I know. But I can't help but agree here: With syntax coloring and even highlighted lines inbetween curly braces, curly braces is FAR superior. I do a lot of work with WooCommerce, and I always remove their endif notation in the templates. It just makes life easier overall.

Answer (score 1):

It is a stylistic choice.  They are analogous and one is not better than another.

The former can be good in certain circumstances because it may be easier to read when mired in the middle of an HTML block set.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use if/endif when stopping and starting the php code block in between, so nearly always when raw html is being outputted.

For example:

```
<?php if ($n == 3): ?>
Lorem ipsum.
<?php endif; ?>
```

This looks, at least in my opinion, better than the following:

```
<?php if ($n == 3) { ?>
Lorem ipsum.
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, but preffered style and currently known style is the standard `if(expr)`.