# Conditional script for a WordPress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am trying to include some JavaScript to just one single page of a WordPress based website. Basically, what I've done is in the header.php of the theme, I've put the following:

```
<?php if( is_page('17')) { ?>
<!--Start of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
$.src="//v2.zopim.com/?2pL2gooCVnWNWjh0QB7IVqRgAiarsW4o";z.t=+new Date;$.
type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
<!--End of Zopim Live Chat Script-->
<?php }
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I add this, it breaks the entire site, nothing loads anywhere. I've tried it with and without the

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

at the end, thinking that it may be duplicating with the

```
<?php }
```

I actually have two different conditional statements I need to add, each for a different page. I don't want to use the plugin that allows PHP & JavaScript in the pages themselves for security reasons, which is what I used to use.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and/or how to add this particular JavaScript to only page #17 (which I'm guessing will also show me how to add a PHP statement and link to single-use stylesheet that I need on a different page)?

Comment: The error could be caused by <?php }
<?php endif; ?> 

Try changing the code to:
<?php }
endif; ?>

Comment: Rats, nope. same issue, once I save, I cannot load any page on the site. all blank, empty pages, so it kills the site.

Comment: I know this shouldn't be difficult, people do this stuff all the time. I'm just learning, so when I google and look at peoples' solutions for their sites none of them seem to work for me, and this example looked the simplest.

Comment: OK. Now you need to either locate and open the site logs or set the php.ini file to show errors that are being generated. Is this site live (available to the public)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a definite answer without seeing the rest of the page code but in my opinion you don't need the `<?php endif; ?>`.

Simply replace

```
<?php }
<?php endif; ?>
```

with

```
<?php } ?>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Awesome, that seemed to do the trick. I'll have to dig into the "why" part so I can become a better programmer, but I really appreciate the help!

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023418/when-do-i-use-if-endif-versus-if) should help you! ps. don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks!